# NetLogo input slider problem, slider disappearing after reset

Tags: netlogo

I want the max value of my input slider to be equal to the number of turtles in my environment. I've done this by inserting "count turtles" in the maximum input box in the slider settings. However, the problem I am facing is that when I (significantly) decrease the number of turtles and setup/reset the slider sort of glitches, stays on the old value (which is larger than the new max value which causes the red knob to disappear) and cannot be changed anymore. A workaround could be to drag the slider completely to the left before resetting the model but this does seem somewhat silly imo. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my minimal working example, I could reset the slider value to `turtle count`, e.g. during setup. I think you could use `if slider_value > count turtles [set slider_value count turtles]` also in the end of the go procedure, in case the number of turtles decreases in your model and you want to keep the slider value updated.

```
globals [
  ; n_turtles - given by slider
  ; slider_value - given by slider
]  

to setup
  clear-all
  crt n_turtles 
  
  if slider_value > count turtles
  [
    set slider_value count turtles
  ]
end
```

Comment: This fixed the problem, thank you very much!